# grails mail plugin error detection

Tags: email, grails

I'm having problems sending e-mails and am trying to determine how to get more information on the failure. The sendMail call succeeds. That is, there are no exceptions thrown. But the e-mail is not delivered. Is there a way to see the status returned from the e-mail server?

Environment:
`grails 2.0.3

mail plugin 1.0`